# Which version should I install? 12.04 LTS or 13.04?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, versions

I'm just about to download and install UBUNTU but I'm confused by the descriptive paragraphs for these versions;
It says that the 12.04 LTS version has support to 2017
But that the latest version 13.04 is only supported for several months!!!!

Which should I download?

Comment: That's entirely up to you.  Which do you prefer?  Upgrade every 6 months, or every few years?

Comment: OK I think I get it. The
What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?  reply explains what I was asking really. This reply would sit nicely as a link beside the releases so that new comers can understand the difference between short and long term support for releases. - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer 12.04 because it offers Long Term Support and it is said to be more stable than 13.04 which is experimental when getting down to some more sophisticated things. Also, you may find yourself with a tool that is not fully compatible with 13.04, while with 12.0.4.3 LTS that is unlikely to happen.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

"Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS is a long-term support release. It has continuous hardware support improvements as well as guaranteed security and support updates until April 2017. "

therefore,use LTS :)